# Linux command run cpp and jar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jar, background-process

I'm new with Linux environment, so sorry for the question.

I have a real time REST API with an app client (Java) and server (C++). I have a Ubuntu machine.

I know that to run C++ it is:

```
$ ./nameOfProgram &
```

and for the Java is:

```
$ java -jar file.jar &
```

The `&` to allow me to continue use the command shell of Linux while my programs are running.

I access to the Ubuntu machine with ssh (with putty) but if I close the connection my programs stop.

What is the best way to always put my programs running in the background even if it is not connected to the machine. My programs are Java and C++, they are in different folders.

Comment: You can use a terminal multiplexer such as `screen` or `tmux`

Comment: Ask on superuser.com, suggested duplicate: [How do I detach a process from Terminal, entirely?](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run your java program even when you exit out of your shell, [Nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) is the simplest way.

It'll detach a process you run from your current console and let it continue when you close the terminal. Run something like this.

```
nohup java -jar my.jar &
```

By default, it will pipe the output to nohup.out, so if you don't want that you could try:

```
nohup java -jar my.jar > /dev/null &
```

Comment: But if i now to see the output? Because when i receive some request i have some prints and for know to the tests i need so see

Comment: Try this: `nohup java -jar my.jar >> /var/log/myservice.log  2>>&1 &`

Comment: And you can mark this as an answer if this works for you.